# Windows Azure Toolkit

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, ipad, azure

I'm trying to build and run some of the example apps included in the Windows Azure Toolkit [here](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios), but it can't seem to find `libwatoolkitios.a` which is a required file for build. I have not modified the project in any way and I would assume that this file should be included automatically, so how do I get it? How have you guys been able to compile the apps successfully? Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The library libwatoolkitios.a is not provided as download instead you would need to build it first, [described in the doc](https://github.com/WindowsAzure-Toolkits/wa-toolkit-ios/blob/master/README.md) as below:

1. Open the watoolkit-lib Xcode project.
2. Compile the project for release.
3. Place the .a file and the header files somewhere that you can reference from your project (for this example lets say lib).